# HTML/CSS Issue with FA Icon & Text Wrapping

Tags: html, css

I am trying to find the correct way to write text next to an Font Awesome Icon. I would like the text to line up next to the icon, and when the text is lengthened (or the display width is shortened), I would like to to wrap next to the icon in multiple rows of text instead of under the icon.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-8 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    <h1 id="title">Title
    </h1>
    <table id="iiij" align="left" border="0" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1">
      <tbody>
        <tr class="row">
          <td class="cell">
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <div id="header">
      <h4>Header
      </h4>
      <br/>
      <div id="box.img">
        <i class="fas fa-home">
        </i>
        <p id="content"> This icon is a picture of a house. I want the text to wrap square so is does not load below the icon. When the display is changed, for mobile users, it jumps below the icon.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-container margin-top-40">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

     <style>#iiij{
  width:100%;
  }
  .fas.fa-home{
    font-size:36px;
    align-self:start;
    float:left;
  }
  #box.img{
    font-size:10em;
    color:rgb(32, 61, 133);
    padding-left:10px;
    float:left;
    margin-top:16px;
    margin-left:20px;
    margin-right:20px;
    margin-bottom:16px;
    clear:left;
    display:inline-block;
  }
  #title{
    color:rgb(32, 61, 133);
    margin-top:21.44px;
    margin-left:20px;
    margin-right:20px;
    margin-bottom:21.44px;
  }
  #header{
    color:rgb(32, 61, 133);
    margin-top:21.28px;
    margin-left:20px;
    margin-right:20px;
    margin-bottom:21.28px;
  }
  #content{
    color:rgb(85, 85, 85);
    margin-top:16px;
    margin-left:20px;
    margin-right:20px;
    margin-bottom:16px;
    float:left;
    align-self:start;
    display:inline-block;
    clear:inherit;
  }
</style>
```

https://codepen.io/MSchleicher/pen/wONzPb

I would like the icon to align to the left side of the page, and the text to be next to it, as if they were separate columns of content.

Answer (score 3):

Consider switching `#box.img` to display as flex.

```
#box.img {
  display: flex;
}
```

This gives the layout you want.  From there, just adjust the padding as needed.

More information:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox

Comment: @MichaelSchleicher Cool, glad this worked for you.  Please consider checking the green checkmark next to this answer to mark it as the solution for future visitors.